# What could be the damage to share the signing key with an untrusted person?

Tags: android

Assuming this untrusted person don't have access to the console to publish new versions, what could be the risk of sharing signing key and pass with him?

I'm trying to figure out if it's ok to provide key to a new developer for him to generate a reléase binary.

Comment: When the new developer is not going to publish the app, why would he/she need to generate a release apk?

Comment: To upload new binaries for beta testing on fabric

Comment: Well in that case you should trust the person and I don't see any issue with sharing the info with him/her keeping in mind dev console access is not available. Just hope they don't hack into Google server  :D